# I need to write a procedure or view in PL/SQL that shows the payments made over a period of dates

Tags: plsql

I am working with a system, I have two tables 'Invoices' and 'Payments Invoice'.
In the table 'Invoice' you have the columns 'Invoice Date' and 'Due Date'.
What I need to do is an examination or view, where to take the examination of the invoice, and verify in the table 'Payments Invoice' the payments made of that invoice in the period of 'Invoice Date' and 'Due Date'

Comment: is not clear what you want to achieve, please improve your questione with this guideline: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question does need some improving for more clarity but this may help you on your way. This would give you invoices that have at least one payment within the specified date window.

```
SELECT i.InvoiceNumber
FROM Invoice i
WHERE EXISTS ( 
   SELECT NULL
   FROM PaymentInvoice pi
   WHERE pi.InvoiceNumber = i.InvoiceNumber
   AND pi.PaymentDate BETWEEN i.InvoiceDate AND i.DueDate );
```

There are all kinds of complexities to invoices and payments this query doesn't take into account - like the sum of the payment amounts within the date window meeting the invoiced amount, etc.